# Failure to find autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, bootstrapping

I'm stuck on a very basic problem:

I'm trying to use Laravel, which I installed on my windows 7 with composer.
When I try to access my website locally with Wamp, I get the error:

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp\www\sitedirectory\public\protected\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\sitedirectory\public\protected\bootstrap\autoload.php on
>   line 17

Everywhere I can read that all I have to do is run composer install or update.
The problem is that I did run both and nothing has to be updated.
The files are where they are needed so I dont understand what could be the problem.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be my problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: run `composer install` in project directoty

Comment: As I told you, I have done this and composer returns that nothing has to be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer is a tool for managing and installing dependencies.

There should exist a file named `composer.phar` in the directory `C:\wamp\www\sitedirectory\public\protected\`. There you should execute the command `composer.phar install` (on the command line).

Then, the directory `vendor` containing the `autoload.php` etc. should be generated.

If the `composer.phar` does not exist (but at least a file named `composer.json`), follow the steps [explained here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to download composer.

Comment: That was it... I was running the composer update and install in the root of the project and I also had to do it in the public/protected folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please mark this answer as accepted by using the green checkmark if it helped you.